# Is there any Image loader with Bitmap input android

Tags: android, universal-image-loader, image-caching

i need a image loader with bitmap input .All i see is the Image Loader with acceptable URI as input. I need a Image Loader just to cache the image not for downloading.

Comment: bitmap input? so you pass a Bitmap as a param? what Bitmap?

Comment: You can modify your Image Loader class to accept bitmap in place of uri...